# API response doesn't indicate the nature of a rejected question POST

Tags: support, feature-request, api, questions, tags

I have a question, which I post to Stack Overflow. The addition of the answer gets rejected and I know that it is due to the fact that I used the tag `coredata` rather than `core-data`.

When I do this on the Website, I get notified with a nice message that I have the wrong tag:

> You are attempting to create the tag [coredata]; however the tag [core-data] already exists! If you think this new tag should be allowed, raise it on meta

However, when I do this programmatically with my app, I get a generic HTTP 400 error. Is there a way for me to detect this problem or, in fact, similar problems that would prevent the user from posting a question (e.g. Question too short, Question title contains illegal words etc.)?